# Как правильно написать условие для проверки базы данных?

Tags: mysql, сравнение

Например, у меня есть две базы данных вида:

1. Маша  1. 100р
2. Оля   2. 200р
3. Петя  3. 150р

Как мне правильно составить условие вида:
Если у Маши 100р, то берем ее имя? Потом надо его в таблицу занести
БД - mysql

Answer (score 0):

Вот прочитай прочитай документацию по [if else](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) все придельно просто и понятно. Если `X`, то выводить `Y`. И все в таком роде. Обычные условия - ЕСЛИ: ТО. А там что тебе нужно из бд подставь получишь нужный результат.